# Jinja loop on nested list creates empty output

Tags: python, loops, jinja2

I have af list of this structure passed to the template with the name `bars` in Python 3.4:

```
[{'var': 1.18, 'occurrences': [0.0805, 0.0808, 0.0991, 0.0994, 0.2356], 'name': 'item name'},
 {'var': 2.31, 'occurrences': [1.0859, 1.1121, 1.4826, 1.4829, 1.8126, 1.8791], 'name': 'other name'}]
```

I want it to create the following output for each dictionary:

```
% List with names
item 1: item name
item 2: other name

% List with vars
item 1: 1.18
item 2: 2.31

% List with occurences
item 1: 0.0805, 0.0808, 0.0991, 0.0994, 0.2356
item 2: 1.0859, 1.1121, 1.4826, 1.4829, 1.8126, 1.8791
```

The first two are no problem, but I can't get it to loop the occurrence list. I use the following jinja template:

```
{% for item in bars %}
  item {{ loop.index }}: {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in bars %}
  item {{ loop.index }}: {{ item.var }}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in bars recursive %}
  {% if item.occurrences %}
    Item {{ loop.index}}: {{ loop(item.occurrences) }}
  {% else %}
    No content
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives this odd output in the third case:

```
Item 1:       No content
No content
No content
No content
No content

Item 2:       No content
No content
No content
No content
No content
No content
```

That is odd since it seems that it loops each item of the list with occurrences, but it does not pass the test for content. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: All three answers pointed me in the right direction, but @famousgarkin give the most elaborate and flexible answer. I ended up with the following solution:

```
{% for item in bars %} 
  Item {{ loop.index }}: {% for occurrence in item.occurrences %} subitem {{ loop.index }}: {{ occurrence }} {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This lets me enclose each item in separate context, which is what I want. But since this aim was not clear from the start, I wish I could upvote all your answers. Sorry, but thank you all for quick help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to format the nested items using the exact same logic you don't use the recursion.

In your sample, when looping `bars` items, it goes to the correct path, since you can see `Item n:` on the output. Then it descends to a recursive call to process `item.occurrences` items. Now when it asks if `occurrences` exists it's actually asking for `bar.occurrences[i].occurrences[j]`, which of course doesn't have the `occurrences` attribute and it goes the `No content` path. You can see it in action using the following:

```
{% for item in bars recursive %}
  {% if item.occurrences %}
    Item {{ loop.index }}: {{ loop(item.occurrences) }}
  {% else %}
    No content, {{ item.__class__ }}, {{ item }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Yields:

```
Item 1: No content, <type 'float'>, 0.0805
No content, <type 'float'>, 0.0808
No content, <type 'float'>, 0.0991
No content, <type 'float'>, 0.0994
No content, <type 'float'>, 0.2356
...
```

It'll work like this, for example:

```
{% for item in bars %}
  {% if item.occurrences %}
    Item {{ loop.index }}: {{ item.occurrences }}
  {% else %}
    No content
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Yields:

```
Item 1: [0.0805, 0.0808, 0.0991, 0.0994, 0.2356]
Item 2: [1.0859, 1.1121, 1.4826, 1.4829, 1.8126, 1.8791]
```

If you want to iterate on the items yourself to provide your own formatting, you can for example use the [Jinja `join`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#join) filter:

```
{% for item in bars %}
  {% if item.occurrences %}
    Item {{ loop.index }}: {{ item.occurrences|join(', ') }}
  {% else %}
    No content
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Yields:

```
Item 1: 0.0805, 0.0808, 0.0991, 0.0994, 0.2356
Item 2: 1.0859, 1.1121, 1.4826, 1.4829, 1.8126, 1.8791
```

Or loop again to roll entirely custom formatting:

```
{% for item in bars %}
  {% if item.occurrences %}
    Item {{ loop.index }}:
    {% for occurrence in item.occurrences %}
      {{ loop.index }}. {{ occurrence }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    No content
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Yields:

```
Item 1:
1. 0.0805
2. 0.0808
3. 0.0991
4. 0.0994
5. 0.2356
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print out the list.

```
{% for item in bars %} #recursive not needed
  {% if item.occurrences %}
    Item {{ loop.index }}: {{ item.occurrences }} #we're not looping here, just printing out the list
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If `bars` will always have `occurrences`, you won't even need the `if` check.

To print indvidual items from occurrences just iterate over it,

```
Item {{ loop.index}}: {% for occurrence in occurrences %}
                       {{ occurrence }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
                      {% endfor %}
```

If you are going to print out the entire list anyway, you can just use a filter that returns a str representation of the list without the square brackets.

Comment: But then what do I do to make it loop the list and print each item instead of just printing the whole list? By the way, I misunderstood the if-statement, intending to make it check if occurrences was true, but I see now that it was wrong. I don't need that. @vikki

Comment: @Stenskjaer since `occurrences` is a list, you can just iterate over it again, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code.

- managing white space to keep lines as planned
- using filter `join` to create list of occurrences
- removed `recursive` from looping over occurrences (as the data are flat and not nested)

Running this script:

```
from jinja2 import Template

bars = [{'var': 1.18, 'occurrences': [0.0805, 0.0808, 0.0991, 0.0994, 0.2356], 'name': 'item name'},
     {'var': 2.31, 'occurrences': [1.0859, 1.1121, 1.4826, 1.4829, 1.8126, 1.8791], 'name': 'other name'}]
templ_str = """
% List with names
{% for item in bars -%}
    item {{ loop.index }}: {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
% List with vars
{% for item in bars -%}
    item {{ loop.index }}: {{ item.var }}
{% endfor %}
% List with occurrences
{%- for item in bars %}
item {{ loop.index}}:{{" "}}
    {%- if item.occurrences -%}
        {{ item.occurrences|join(", ") }}
    {%- else -%}
    No content
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
"""
templ = Template(templ_str)
print templ.render(bars=bars)
```

You shall get this output:

```
% List with names
item 1: item name
item 2: other name

% List with vars
item 1: 1.18
item 2: 2.31

% List with occurrences
item 1: 0.0805, 0.0808, 0.0991, 0.0994, 0.2356
item 2: 1.0859, 1.1121, 1.4826, 1.4829, 1.8126, 1.8791
```